# Table is exceeding the right margin

Tags: tables

I am having an issue even while using the table, the table is exceeding the right margin.

Below is the code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170 mm,257 mm},
left=20 mm,
top=20 mm,
}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[h]
            \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
            \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{c}\textbf{Operations}\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{3}{c |}{\textbf{Subtraction Magnitudes}} \\
                \cline{2-4}
                            & A $>$ B & A $<$ B & A $=$ B \\
                \hline
                (+A) + (-B) & +(A - B) & -(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
                \hline
                (-A) + (+B) & -(A - B) & +(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
                \hline
                (+A) - (+B) & +(A - B) & -(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
                \hline
                (-A) - (-B) & -(A - B) & +(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
                \hline 
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Subtraction using Signed Magnitude Representation}
\end{table}
```

Can someone please help me to align this table in the center of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tabular` environment in your code fits fine. What's missing is a `\centering` directive, so that the table and its caption are both centered.

Some further suggestions, in no particular order:

- Since almost all contents of the table are "math-y", I'd use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.
- The `palatino` package is obsolete, just as the `times` package is. I suggest you load the `newpxtext` package instead of the `palatino` package. I'd further load the `newpxmath` package, to provide a Palatino-clone math font package. (Palatino text and Computer Modern math do not harmonize well.)
- I can see no reason for **bold-facing** the contents of the table's header row.
- The preamble code contains several minor inefficencies. I've commented on some of them in the code below. Do check if you could remove some of the cruft that's present in your document's preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}    % are you sure this is needed?
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%a4paper,      % this is already set globally
          total={170mm, 257mm},
          left=20mm, top=20mm}
\usepackage{%amsmath,    % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
    bm}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
%%\usepackage{palatino}  % 'palatino' package is deprecated 
\usepackage{newpxtext}   % <-- more modern than 'palatino' package
\usepackage{newpxmath}   % <-- Palatino-clone math font

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%%\usepackage{xcolor}    % don't load packages twice
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    % are you sure this is needed?
\usepackage{array}       % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arydshln}    % are you sure this is needed?
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}       % are you sure this is needed?
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % I've added 'normalem' option
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % nice touch!
\centering % <-- new
$\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c |} % suggest using 'array' instead of 'tabular'
    \hline
    \multirow{2.1}{*}{\textnormal{Operations}} & % first arg. of '\multirow' needn't be integer-valued
      \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textnormal{Subtraction magnitudes}}\\
    \cline{2-4}
                & A > B    & A < B    & A = B    \\
    \hline
    (+A) + (-B) & +(A - B) & -(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
    \hline
    (-A) + (+B) & -(A - B) & +(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
    \hline
    (+A) - (+B) & +(A - B) & -(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
    \hline
    (-A) - (-B) & -(A - B) & +(B - A) & +(A - B) \\
    \hline 
\end{array}$

\caption{Subtraction using signed magnitude representation}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `\begin{figure}[h]` is not a good idea…

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for noticing this. Now fixed.

Comment: Even better `[htp]`.

Comment: @egreg -- or `[htbp]` :-)

Comment: Thanks. It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of nice @Mico answer (+1). Main differences:

- for table are used `tabularray` package (with it the table code is quite shorter)
- positioning of floats are defined globally
- at `geometry` package is used only `margin` options

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{newpxtext}    
\usepackage{amssymb, bm, mathtools} % should be loaded before newpxmath
\usepackage{newpxmath}    

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
% global float positioning
\makeatletter
    \def\fps@figure{hbtp}
    \def\fps@table{hbtp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering  
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { *{4}{Q[c, mode=math]} },
             row{1}  = {mode=text},
             rowsep=4pt
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{} Operations 
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{} Subtraction magnitudes  
                &           &               \\
    & A > B     & A < B     & A = B         \\
(+A) + (-B) 
    & +(A - B)  & -(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
(-A) + (+B) 
    & -(A - B)  & +(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
(+A) - (+B) 
    & +(A - B)  & -(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
(-A) - (-B) 
    & -(A - B)  & +(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Subtraction using signed magnitude representation}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
or you may more liked the following design:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=20mm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{newpxtext}    
\usepackage{amssymb, bm, mathtools} % should be loaded before newpxmath
\usepackage{newpxmath}    

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,
                booktabs}   % new
% global float positioning
\makeatletter
    \def\fps@figure{hbtp}
    \def\fps@table{hbtp}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering  
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{4}{Q[c, mode=math]} },
             column{1} = {rightsep=2em},    % new
             column{2-Y} = {colsep+=2pt},
             row{1}  = {mode=text},
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{} Operations 
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{} Subtraction magnitudes  
                &           &               \\
    \midrule
    & A > B     & A < B     & A = B         \\
    \midrule
(+A) + (-B) 
    & +(A - B)  & -(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
(-A) + (+B) 
    & -(A - B)  & +(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
(+A) - (+B) 
    & +(A - B)  & -(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
(-A) - (-B) 
    & -(A - B)  & +(B - A)  & +(A - B)      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Subtraction using signed magnitude representation}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 as well. :-) Is there a need for `rowsep=4pt` in the second table, though? I'm all in favor of an open "look", but is increasing `rowsep` the way to go? If anything, I'd advocate running `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! You are right. In the second example bigger row separations are not needed. Increase column separation has more sense. I will change bots ASAP!